# Visual Studio Code: how to prioritize one formatting provider over the other

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm coding PHP and using a few extensions that are very useful:

- [PHP Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sophisticode.php-formatter) just for formatting code
- [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) for providing intellisense

In this case both of them are Formatting providers, so you can right click in your editor and select "Format document" and everything will get indented and beautiful.... you get the point.

The thing here is that the formatting done by the PHP Intelephense (which I don't like) is the one that stays.

If, for instance, I disable the Intelephense extension the formatting looks good.

Let me give you a visual difference between the two formatting:

Intelephense (bad):

```
    if ($condition) {
        doSomthing();
    }
    else {
        doAnotherThing();
    }
```

PHP formatter (good) [chek out the else]

```
    if ($condition) {
        doSomthing();
    } else {
        doAnotherThing();
    }
```

Zanks in advance for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you determine which formatter is being used for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640469/how-do-you-determine-which-formatter-is-being-used-for-vs-code)

Answer (score 4):

"intelephense.format.enable": false 
This will do your work.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic way to choose one over the other. This is left to extension authors to handle via settings as explained in the docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/11/15/formatters-best-practices#_multiple-formatters)

> What happens when there are multiple formatters for one language? This
>   can be a problem when different formatters' actions contradict. In the
>   October release, we added settings to enable or disable the default
>   formatters that ship with VS Code. The best practice is for extension
>   authors to add a similar setting as what we did in VS Code as shown
>   below.
>
> ```
> "html.format.enable": true,
> "javascript.format.enable": true,
> "typescript.format.enable": true,
> "json.format.enable": true
> ```

You can read more discussion on how they came to this in this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11609).

So what does this mean for you? It means that the intelliphense extension needs to add a setting to disable formatting. You can create [an issue](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues) and wait for them to fix it or try to make a PR to fix it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, What is a PR? I googled it but only got 'Public Relations'.

Comment: A PR is a "pull request". It is the GitHub way of suggesting code changes to somebody else's code. You create a copy of it, make changes, and then make a "pull request" to them with those changes. If they like them, they can accept them.