# VScode rotates multiple formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the uncrustify extension from LaurentTreguier which worked as intented.
But now vscode started to rotate formatter when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Means one time uncrustify is executed and the next time some other formatter, which i don't know. I also have the C/C++ extension from MS installed.

And only configured uncrustify for the workspace.

How can i set the command to only use uncrustify? Or how can see which other formatter is used. Is there a other way besides looking the debbuging terminal for uncrustify to determine which code formatter was executed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you determine which formatter is being used for VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640469/how-do-you-determine-which-formatter-is-being-used-for-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to disable the formatter which comes with the `C/C++ Extension`, so in this case the cpp_fromatter.

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `settings` choose `Preferences: Open User Settings` and add this line.

```
/* Disable cpp code formatter in favour of uncrustify */
"C_Cpp.formatting": "Disabled",
```