# VSCode's format-on-save setting conflicts with prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, prettier

Our extension uses VSCode's `format on save` setting.

However, our extension somehow prevents `prettier` to run - when a file is saved, our extension is fired, but the `prettier` isn't.
I assume that prettier uses the same setting, and that our extension is registered/fired before it.

Is there a way to not prevent `prettier` from running?

Comment: VSCode is not designed to run multiple formatters on a file type, with the 1.33 release this will become even more explicit by forcing you to select one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55431401/2631715

Comment: VSCode's formatter support is pretty bad. It takes multiple seconds to format a file of any significant with most formatters, and then things like this happen because Microsoft doesn't take into account the fact that it takes multiple seconds to format a file of any significant with most formatters.

Answer (score 8):

Try it, it's working for me, and make sure `esbenp.prettier-vscode` is installed.

```json
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
}
```