# How can I troubleshoot if VSCode is using my ESLint and/or Prettier configurations or something else?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

This is a question about troubleshooting VSCode and/or ESLint and/or Prettier. I've got them all set up in my project, but I'm unclear about how they are interacting.

On the lower right-hand corner of every editor, it shows this:

[image]

I don't see it mention anything about ESLint though. (Is that implied?)

Although I don't have a `.prettierrc` (or whatever it should be called) in my project, my ESLint is configured like so:

```json
  // ...
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier", // <--------------------------------- of note
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:testcafe/recommended"
  ],
  // ...
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "testcafe"
  ],
  // ...
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [
      "off"
    ],
    // ...
  }
```

Here are my questions:

1. How do I configure VSCode to format/prettify and lint the same way as running `eslint` from the command line?
2. When I format or lint a document in VSCode, how do I troubleshoot which program/extension/setting/configuration performed the action?

Either one of these would answer my question. You don't have to answer both.

---

### Example

The following is an ***example***: I am not trying to solve this specific problem. I'm merely documenting confusing behavior:

If I change the "quotes.off" rule (see above) to "quotes.error", VSCode will error on lines like these:

```
return 'foo';
// Strings must use doublequote. eslint(quotes)
```

By that account, VSCode seems to be using my configuration file. If I then run `eslint '**/*.ts' --fix` from the command line, almost every single-quote (`'`) in my project will be changed to double-quotes (`"`). So far so good.

But strangely, if I use VSCode's "Format Document" action, it reverts all these double-quotes back to single-quotes, introducing errors.

To me it feels like it's using one configuration for reporting errors and another for formatting, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I'm not even sure which program is causing the problem; it could even be the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) or [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extensions I've installed, as opposed to the project configuration files.

---

### Complete Configuration Files

##### .eslintrc.json

```js
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": false,
    "jasmine": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:testcafe/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly",
    "State": "writable",
    "setup": "writable"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "project": "./tsconfig.base.json"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "testcafe"
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [
      "off"
    ],
    "no-plusplus": [
      "off"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
      2
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": [
      2
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": [
      "off"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": [
      "off"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": [
      "off"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      "off"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": [
      "off"
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-asserted-optional-chain": [
      "off"
    ],
    "prefer-const": [
      "warn"
    ]
  }
}
```

##### User settings.json

```js
{
  "telemetry.telemetryLevel": "off",
  "editor.fontSize": 20,
  "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "CHERE_INVOKING": "1"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "--login",
    "-i"
  ],
  "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "eslint.runtime": "node",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "typescript.format.semicolons": "insert",
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary",
  "files.enableTrash": false,
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
  },
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.classpath": true,
    "**/.factorypath": true,
    "**/.git": false,
    "**/.project": true,
    "**/.settings": true
  },
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 500,
  "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 18,
  "terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "paste",
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
  "window.title": "${dirty}${appName}${separator}${rootName}${separator}${activeEditorShort}",
  "editor.codeLensFontSize": 20,
  "editor.inlayHints.fontSize": 20,
  "editor.suggestFontSize": 20,
  "scm.inputFontSize": 20,
  "debug.console.fontSize": 20,
  "markdown.preview.fontSize": 20,
  "editor.fontFamily": "'JetBrains Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.lineHeight": 1.2,
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection": "selection",
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "svg.preview.mode": "svg",
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "debug.onTaskErrors": "abort",
  "explorer.excludeGitIgnore": false,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "terminal.integrated.enableMultiLinePasteWarning": false,
  "explorer.incrementalNaming": "smart",
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true
  },
  "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Cygwin": {
      "path": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "args": [
        "--login",
        "-i"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Cygwin",
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

##### Workspace settings.json

```js
{
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
  "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.quoteProps": "preserve",
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
  "editor.fontSize": 20,
  "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
  "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
    "default": "right",
    "jupyter-notebook": "left"
  },
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/node_modules": false
  },
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "CHERE_INVOKING": "1"
  },
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "--login",
    "-i"
  ],
  "window.openFoldersInNewWindow": "on",
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules\\typescript\\lib",
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": false
  }
}
```

These are my Visual Studio Code default formatters:

[image]

These appear to be the same for my user and workspace settings. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to give me any clues as to what's modifying the first one elsewhere. I can imagine these would cause issues as selecting `prettier` in a drop down might bypass my ESLint configuration?

BTW, my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: To troubleshoot the [eslint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint), look at the "output" of the extension.

Comment: @Bergi I have tons of extensions installed, but in my question I linked to my ESLint and Prettier extensions.

Comment: @Bergi When I run VSCode's "Format Document", that tab does not print anything. I guess this confirms that ESLint isn't *directly* used for formatting. I'm investigating the Prettier tab now; it does print on format.

Comment: "*if I use VSCode's "Format Document" action*" - that's probably using the `editor.defaultFormatter` you've configured. Does the output of the [prettier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) print anything?

Comment: @Bergi It does and I'm investigating.

Comment: …or it might just use vscode's builtin javascript/typescript formatters, which you have set to `"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single", "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"` - that would explain why it's changing it back to single quotes. Notice you also have `"prettier.singleQuote": true` which might conflict with this.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not able to glean from the Prettier output tab who called/configured it. If it's ESLint, it's not passing its rules to it; there are only three rules it's using that have the word "quote" in it: `{  ... "jsxSingleQuote": true,  "quoteProps": "preserve",  "singleQuote": true, ...}`

Comment: @Bergi `…or it might just use vscode's builtin javascript/typescript formatters` I'm inferring that I do, in fact, need to have knowledge about all of these possibilities in order to confidently fix this. At the bottom of my question I've shared the user and workspace `settings.json`, respectively, so the answer might be there?

Comment: @Bergi is there a way to tell VSCode to prefer eslint/prettier settings instead of its own? (i.e., question #1?)

Comment: "*If it's ESLint, it's not passing its rules to it*" - what do you mean by that? I don't see any prettier config in your eslint file (and prettier won't care about the `quotes` rule). I'm not sure where prettier would take its config from then, you say you don't use a *.prettierrc* file, not sure if it might take the "prettier extension" settings when called via eslint - it might just use its defaults.

Comment: "*is there a way to tell VSCode to prefer eslint/prettier settings instead of its own?*" - no. The builtin formatter does not know about these extensions and cannot depend on their behaviour. (I doubt there's a hook for extensions to change the autoformatter settings). I would recommend either changing the `defaultFormatter`, or aligning the settings (like quote style) wherever you find some.

Comment: (But I'm mostly guessing here, so I won't write an answer - it would indeed be nice to get an authoritative reference)

Comment: @Bergi Update: I show my `defaultFormatter` settings at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1):

ESLint is a linter, while Prettier is a formatter.

> Linters usually contain not only code quality rules, but also stylistic rules. Most stylistic rules are unnecessary when using Prettier, but worse – they might conflict with Prettier! Use Prettier for code formatting concerns, and linters for code-quality concerns. [Prettier Docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html)

Putting the eslint prettier config into your eslint config will disable rules that interfere with prettier. Regarding question #1, running eslint does not lint your code, it only outputs errors. The only exception to this would be running `eslint --fix`, which will fix certain issues with your code, including stylistic ones if you choose to add that to your config, for example with the eslint prettier plugin (not the same as eslint prettier config). If you'd like to do that, you can follow this [tutorial by DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/workflow-auto-eslinting).

For question #2, if you'd like to determine what formatter is running, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640469/how-do-you-determine-which-formatter-is-being-used-for-vs-code), you can look through your VSCode configuration to find the specific default formatter for that language. In your workspace config, this is what it shows:

```json
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  },
```

And in your user config:

```json
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features" // VSCode built in json formatter
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features" // VSCode built in javascript formatter
  },
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" // Prettier
  }
```

If you want to determine what linter is giving you which error, after the error, it will tell you the extension giving the message. [image]

Comment: I've read that documentation many times and I'm not sure I understand it. Does the quoted note apply to the entire page or just everything below it? Because the only reason I'm using [`"prettier"`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) in my ESLint configuration is because I thought that documentation was telling me it's the preferred thing to do?

Comment: The prettier config makes the separation of duties more clear, by disabling stylistic rules in eslint, and leaving those to prettier. It is recommended that you use that config, so you can leave linting for eslint, and formatting to prettier.

Comment: The part below the part that I quoted from that page details if you did want to have everything done by ESLint, integrating prettier directly into the rules of eslint.

Comment: I'm interpreting what you said as: 1) you followed Prettier's recommendation by setting `"extends": ["prettier"]` in your `.eslintrc.json` because 2) that disables eslint stylistic rules. Can you confirm?

Comment: (As an aside, what's throwing me off is, in my mind, I've already taken some of the steps in the answer. If you haven't already, could you remove the steps I've already taken so the answer only includes what I need to change?)